# mysql explain type index vs all performance question

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, group-by, mariadb

I have the following table below: I have 3.5 million records.

[image]

```sql
CREATE TABLE `video_downloads` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `video_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `download_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3573041 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Only `id` and `user_id` are `indexed`.

Here is my query:

```sql
select max(video_id), user_id
from video_downloads
group by user_id
```

With this current table setup, this query took me about more than 10 mins to run.
So here is the `explain`

```
| id | select_type | table           | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref | rows    | Extra |
|----|-------------|-----------------|-------|---------------|---------|---------|-----|---------|-------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | video_downloads | index |               | user_id | 8       |     | 3562709 |       |
```

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "video_downloads",
      "access_type": "index",
      "key": "user_id",
      "key_length": "8",
      "used_key_parts": ["user_id"],
      "rows": 3562709,
      "filtered": 100
    }
  }
}
```

And then I removed the index for `user_id` running the same query and it took me about `1.5 s`.

Here is the `explain` without `user_id` index

```
| id | select_type | table           | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows    | Extra                           |
|----|-------------|-----------------|------|---------------|-----|---------|-----|---------|---------------------------------|
| 1  | SIMPLE      | video_downloads | ALL  |               |     |         |     | 3562709 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
```

```json
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "filesort": {
      "sort_key": "video_downloads.user_id",
      "temporary_table": {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "video_downloads",
          "access_type": "ALL",
          "rows": 3562709,
          "filtered": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think my main question is why there is such a huge difference in terms of the time with and without the index on `user_id`. And when there is an index on `user_id` the `type` is `index` which means it's using the index but the query is very slow.

I am a bit confused with the result I do not think I understand why this is happening, I check the [official doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#jointype_index) still not fully understand it.

**update** I think the main reason could be it's using the `index` data to fetch the row from disk, and it's going to do it one by one and randomly. So that's 3.5 million times random read from disk. That's the only reason I can think of. However, is that going to be that slow? (more than `10 mins` vs `1.5 s` ???).

However, from [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-btree-hash.html)

> Sometimes MySQL does not use an index, even if one is available. One circumstance under which this occurs is when the optimizer estimates that using the index would require MySQL to access a very large percentage of the rows in the table.

In my case, MySQL does not seem to take the right decision. I can see the `possible_keys` is `null` but `key` is still using the index why? is it because of the `group by`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the plans.  They don't seem to be doing aggregation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff any help or advice would be much appreciated. or do I need to provide more info?

Comment: It's  always annoying to provide information in pictures instead of using plain text.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there are too many subtle issues that are left out when you try to simplify the table definition.

Comment: Yes to I/O-bound; I updated my answer to partially explain it.  The table is about 300MB, correct?

Comment: @RickJames yes it's 344M

Comment: @RickJames Hi I think I understand most of this, just one last point which is the `possible_keys` vs `key` for my query, I also updated it at the end of my question, can you share more thought on that, please?

Comment: @AndySong -  "possible keys" is a list of some of the indexes on the table.  (id) would not be useful.  "key" is the index it actually used.  (It is unusual for "key" to list an index that is not in "possible keys".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "statistics" that the Optimizer uses are not always perfect.  However "10 min" vs "1.5 sec" is quite spectacular.  I wonder if there was outside interference.  Oh, what Engine is being used?

When it used the single-column index, it probably had to bounce between the index and the data, fetching 3.5M rows one at a time, but randomly.

When it did the table scan ("All"), it also read 3.5M rows, but sequentially.  But then it had to followup with a sort.

**Buffer_pool**

16M for `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the problem.  Set that to about 70% of RAM size unless you have an especially small machine.

The 10-minute query was probably solid I/O, reading and rereading the data from the table *randomly*.

On a spinning disk (HDD, not SDD), 3.5M reads at 100 blocks/second is several hours.  So you were lucky to get finished in *only* 10 minutes.  The 1.5s says how useful a big enough RAM cache is.

The 1.5s may be all it took to read straight (not randomly) through the entire table once.

Comment: I have updated my question, do you know more why this is happening?

Comment: @AndySong - Alas, no obvious explanation.  One more question:  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size;`

Comment: `'innodb_buffer_pool_size'` is `16777216`

Comment: @AndySong - That's it.  What version?  How much RAM?  I added to my answer.

Comment: And `INDEX(user_id, video_id)` should run even faster.

Comment: hi thank you for your explanation, I just do not understand this `16M for innodb_buffer_pool_size is the problem. Set that to about 70% of RAM size unless you have an especially small machine.` can u explain more about this?

Comment: `What version? How much RAM?` are you asking my db version? and my machine ram?

Comment: What version of MySQL or MariaDB (whichever you are using)?  How much RAM in your computer or in the VM or the cloud service you are using.  It will probably be some number of GB (gigabytes).  More info after I see those.  Meanwhile, this may provide a little more insight:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory .

Comment: `MariaDB 10.4.14`, and `16 GB` for RAM.